# URL Routing/Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, http, url

I'm working on a website in which I have a folder structure that is organized but creates a long and not "Pretty URL". What I was wondering how would I accomplish a URL Routing/Rewrite from say:

```
https://DOMIAN.NAME/resources/views/back-end/FILENAME.php
```

to simply

```
https://DOMAIN.NAME/FILENAME (no extension)
```

Is this possible? Would it be .htaccess rewrite or PHP or something else? Also through the same way how would I make it so that if some one types `http` it will direct them to same URL but with `https`?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!

I'm not sure if I missed type or something but I was able to get the code to work in which was listed on Digital Ocean's blog! I thought I used the same code but must have; like mentioned, typed something wrong or used a completely different code!

[The Article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-centos-7)

The Code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^FILENAME$ /resources/views/back-end/FILENAME.php [NC]
```

Which is basically doing:

- RewriteRule = The rule statement
- ^ = Looks/keeps the information before the "NEW" variable
- FILENAME = The "NEW" variable / or page URI
- $ = Includes whatever else is in the URL
- resources/views/back-end/FILENAME.php = The "OLD" variable or current URI / file path
- [NC] = Allows for the variables to be types in any case types such as "filename", "FILENAME", "FileName", etc.